# How to disable button cell when clicked in for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a double for loop in my React code and I am wanting to correctly disable a button when it is clicked. I tried possibly sending in an array and clicking the button but this is erroring out every time. This seems like it should be easier than I am making it. How can I disable the correct button when it is clicked?

```
state = {
        updated: [],
        key: 0
    };
```

Here is my CustomTable

```
const CustomTable = ({ element, handleUpdate, updated, key}) => (
    <Table>
        <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Type</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Update</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
        {Object.keys(element).map(function(dataType) {
            return (
                Object.keys(element[dataType]).map(function(data, i){
                    return (
                        <Table.Row key = {i}>
                            <Table.Cell>{data + " " + dataType}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>
                            <Button content='Update Row' color='green' disabled = {updated.indexOf(key) > 1}
                                style={{margin: 0}} 
                                onClick = {() => handleUpdate(key)}
                                />
                            </Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        );
                    })
            )})
        }

        </Table.Header>
</Table>

);
```

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like, the element that you're getting as prop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use React state to keep track of the enabled/disabled state of each button. Then in `render()` you use that state to enable/disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
const SomeComponentAbove = () => {
   const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

   const handleUpadte = async () => {
     setDisabled(true);
     await doSomething();
     setDisabled(false);
   }

   return <CustomTable handleUpdate={handleUpdate} disabled={updated.indexOf(key) > -1} key={key} />
}



const CustomTable = ({ element, handleUpdate, disabled, key}) => (
  <Table>
      <Table.Header>
      <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Type</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Update</Table.HeaderCell>
      </Table.Row>
      {Object.keys(element).map(function(dataType) {
          return (
              Object.keys(element[dataType]).map(function(data, i){
                  return (
                      <Table.Row key = {i}>
                          <Table.Cell>{data + " " + dataType}</Table.Cell>
                          <Table.Cell>
                          <Button content='Update Row' color='green' disabled = {disabled}
                              style={{margin: 0}} 
                              onClick = {() => handleUpdate(key)}
                              />
                          </Table.Cell>
                      </Table.Row>
                      );
                  })
          )})
      }

      </Table.Header>
</Table>

);
```

You create a component without a state which is just using the props you give it to show some visual representation. In your handleUpdate function you need to manage the state change, so the component which is rendering CustomTable needs to take care of that. You need to change "update" to set the button to be disabled or not.